# Set clipping rectangle for OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl

I'm making a drawing application with WINAPI and OpenGL. To make things more efficient I only redraw the region needed so I invalidateRect(hwnd,myRect,false).
I know OpenGL does self clipping but I want to do that for my rect. I want it to clip itself for the region I invalidated to make things even more efficient. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want is the scissor test. Enable it with `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);` and set the scissor rectangle with `glScissor(x, y, width, height);`