# How can I draw around a rectangle?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, mfc

I'm using openGL to draw some animation.

I want to draw the animation in an area around a rectangle.
That rectangle are should be transparent, to show whatever windows happen to be there, and leave that to regular windows MFC drawings.

I know there should be away to do it with clipping. But since whatever is in that rectangle isn't drawn with the openGL I'm not sure that will work well.

I'm using openGL with c++.

Comment: Will your code be along side the process that draws the MFC windows? Or are you coding a separate interface using OpenGL that must draw around an existing MFC based application?

Comment: The OpenGL is in a separate MFC control OnDraw(). And I need it to draw around a separate MFC control

Comment: If you can get the co-ordinates of the rectangle and dimensions, then this should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915071/set-clipping-rectangle-for-opengl (Using the Scissor test)

Comment: Nope, it still draws over the rest of the image. Maybe somethign to do with the SwapBuffers ? And btw, it draws only in that rectangle, so it's the opposite of what i need.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong one, try the Stencil buffer - http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/sig99/advanced99/notes/node117.html

Comment: Yeah, as arunkumar said: The stencil buffer is what you need here. +1 to his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

If you are drawing over unrelated windows, you should use Stencil buffer.
This can be used as a masking layer to decide where you want to draw.

If you have an MFC window with a child window, you can create the "father" window with the following style: **`WS_CLIPCHILDREN`**